# amzon SP-API ,The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided

Tags: php

Errors appear when I encrypt and upload the feed data

> the document link :https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/guides/use-case-guides/feeds-api-use-case-guide-2020-09-04.md#step-2-encrypt-and-upload-the-feed-data

I develop in php,and the composer is `composer require double-break/spapi-php`

```
$feeder = new Feeder();
$feeder->uploadFeedDocument($docPayload, 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
        //ROOT_PATH.'uploads/amz/'.$feedFileName
        'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/xsd/release_4_1/OrderAcknowledgement.xsd'
    );
```

Errors appear when I encrypt and upload the feed data:

[image]

Comment: this could happen if your aws4 sign does not match with what amazon is calculating, check your headers and they signed correctly.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure content type you pass to `createFeedDocument` matches exactly the content type you pass to `Feeder::uploadFeedDocument`. In my case I was passing `text/tab-separated-values` to the former but `text/tab-separated-values; charset=UTF-8` to the latter (with charset appended) and was getting the error you're describing. I fixed it by passing `text/tab-separated-values; charset=UTF-8` in both instances.

Comment: It blows me away that not only does the type matter, but the case of the friggin charset matters...FFS...charset=utf-8 vs charset=UTF-8 with the former creating the error, the latter giving an OKAY.  God I despise AMZ and SPAPI.  Thank you, that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with this comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/67474344/12360781

But a more elaborative answer would be that we should pass these headers to the `PUT` request and of course the `content-type` should be the same as we passed to `CreateFeedDocument` operation.

`{"Content-Type": "text/tab-separated-values; charset=UTF-8"}`

This piece of code worked for me in Ruby:

`faraday_connection = Faraday::Connection.new(@url)`

`@response = faraday_connection.send(:put, nil, @data.to_json, { "Content-Type": "text/tab-separated-values; charset=UTF-8" })`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and after spending three days searching for the solution at last I come up with the following solution although I was using the Github C# sdk but the error was the same.

I was missing two important header required and after providing them fixed the issue for me.

Following is the code (C#)

```
restRequest.AddOrUpdateHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
restRequest.AddOrUpdateHeader("User-Agent", "XXXX 2022");
```

Best of Luck!!!